# Logstash and Multiline Log Entry from Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, logstash-grok

We are sending CF logs message to an ELK stack. Multiline logs message are broken out into several log messages in Logstash. One end per line of the multiline log message. This is problematic when stack traces dumped to the log. Each line of the stack trace is translated into a log message. Trying to view this through Kibana is nearly impossible. Logstash provides a Grok feature allowing for the manipulation of the log messages. One common solution is to create a Grok filter that using a timestamp to indicate when a log entry starts and to combine all lines until the next timestamp into one log message. The problem is that CF adds a timestamp to every line. Has anyone come up with a good Grok expression to handle multiline log messages coming out of CF?

Here's a snippet of a log from Cloud Foundry. In Logstash, each line is seen as a separate log message

```
2015-07-24T10:37:59.93-0600 [App/0]      OUT  org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://11.11.11.11:9191/someendpoint":Connect to 11.11.11.11:9191 [/11.11.11.11] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 11.11.11.11:9191 [/11.11.11.11] failed: Connection refused
2015-07-24T10:37:59.93-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580)
2015-07-24T10:37:59.93-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
2015-07-24T10:37:59.93-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForLocation(RestTemplate.java:305)
2015-07-24T10:37:59.93-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at com.digitalglobe.p2020.eventservice.sendevent.EventSenderCommand.run(EventSenderCommand.java:104)
```

Comment: Can you provide a log example to these log messages?

If there is a timestamp on every line, how do you, as a person, find an indication that a new multi-line message is starting?

Comment: @TomKregenbild thanks for your interest. I added a snippet from the Cloud Foundry log stream.

Comment: Hi, 
I am trying to do the same thing trying to get timestamp,host,requester,response_time,app_id,agent used and many other things from Cloud Foundry log listed below 

2015-08-03T09:51:15.000+00:00 [RTR] OUT mm1-spring-music.example.com - [03/08/2015:09:51:15 +0000] "GET /assets/ HTTP/1.1" 200 428 "http://mm1--music.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36" XX.XX.XXX.XX" vcap_request_id:5ad0-f9-46a9-77-2095952faf78response_time:0.002043376 app_id:08b8-c7-4613-bf12-1a

Can you share logstash.conf you have used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logs you provided I see that you have the first message of the multiline and then the rest of the messages are indented by additional two spaces after the OUT part.

This means that you should be able to catch the first line using the following pattern

```
^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\s+\[%{DATA}]\s+\S+\s{2}\S
```

Please notice that it should not catch the preceding lines and only the first one and if you change the value of s{2} to s{4} you will catch the presiding lines and not the first one (the opposite of what you want).

Comment: thanks for the solution. This works well if there's one Logstash server, but in a multi server environment it doesn't work because Cloud Foundry could send each line to a different server. I'm wondering if it's more of a Cloud Foundry issue to ensure all lines from a multiline log message are sent to the same Logstash server.

Comment: You can overcome this issue by implementing the multiline logic on the shipper that sends the logs to the logstash server. 

You can use the Beaver shipper for this and read more about how to solve it at the end of this article I wrote under "The Multiline Problem":

http://logs101.com/the-message-broker-scaling-logstash-part-3/